# How to change keyboard layout for startup (passphrase prompt)?

Tags: keyboard-layout

How do I permanently change the keyboard layout for the passphrase prompt during startup?

Comment: What do you mean by startup? The lvm startup or the login startup or the bios startup or the grub startup?

Comment: when it tries to unlock the lvm volumes.

Comment: You can not. It uses standard US keyboard layout.

Comment: What about modifying the initrd?

Comment: Go through this link on your own risk. http://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#Set_Keyboard_Layout_in_initramfs But I dont think lvm offers to use keyboard layout other than US. Its not possible. If you are a developer you might wish to contribute this feature.
Follow that link only if you know what you are doing. It may cause software failure or data corruption.

Comment: and also this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/how-to-set-keyboard-layout-used-to-enter-password-on-an-encrypted-filesystem

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/q/110838/65926

Comment: As Ubuntu is a different system than Debian, the proposed solution (editing "/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf" file) did not work with my xubuntu distro. However, I found the solution following this post ([https://askubuntu.com/questions/810984/keyboard-layout-ignored-in-initramfs-since-kernel-4-4-0-34-how-to-use-non-us-la](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810984/keyboard-layout-ignored-in-initramfs-since-kernel-4-4-0-34-how-to-use-non-us-la)) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For me, simply setting `KEYMAP=Y` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` worked -- I am now able to use my console's keymap for entering the LUKS passphrase.

```
echo "KEYMAP=Y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
update-initramfs -u
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#Set_Keyboard_Layout_in_initramfs