# Keyboard layout ignored in initramfs since kernel 4.4.0-34. How to use non-US layout?

Tags: boot, kernel, keyboard-layout, initramfs

I use a German keyboard layout and a luks-encrypted harddrive on my up-to-date 16.04. I could enter my luks password using my German keyboard layout with no problems until I installed the latest kernel update 4.4.0-34-generic. Now the layout is en_US for the cryptsetup on boot, but after that it's all German (e.g. for login).

I can still select to boot the old kernel 4.4.0-31-generic and have the German keyboard layout on cryptsetup.

I tried adding "KEYMAP=y" to my /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf and rebuilding my initramfs with "sudo update-initramfs -u", but that did not help.

How can I set a keyboard layout on cryptsetup with the newest kernel?

Answer (score 3):

`KEYMAP=y` is a Debian only mechanism and therefore only usable in Debian. It gets passed in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/keymap` located in `initramfs-tools` package and generates the later used `/etc/boottime.kmap.gz`.

`initramfs-tools` in Ubuntu provides entirely different hooks and they do not use `KEYMAP=y`. But those scripts always try to load the configured local keymap.
`/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/console_setup` will copy the existing `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz` to the small busybox environment.
Later `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/console_setup` will then load this keymap.

Btw. it seems to that `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/keymap` will also try to load in the same way `/etc/boottome.kmap.gz`, but this file do not exist (it was used in former times).

However `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/console_setup` do not generate `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz` and just use the existing one, in contrast to Debian. I assume that the generation has to do once right and then it should work again and then call ´update-initramfs -u`.

However, it seems to I was not able to do it right at that point. What worked is a bit disappointing: I had to install the whole OS again. Make sure you have selected your correct keyboard layout during the installation process and run ´update-initramfs -u` in a chroot environment of the new system after the installation process but before booting into the new installed system (I tested that btw.)

Comment: One day a few weeks ago I had a kernel update and it suddenly worked again. Without changing any config or keyboard setting. I assume it was a regression which took a few months to fix.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation of how Ubuntu is different, that helped a lot! Because of your answer I have found this Launchpad report that had a proposed solution that worked for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1719612/comments/4

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on a **fresh install* of ubuntu 17.10**.

This bit of information by F.Raab was proven very useful:

> However /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/console_setup do not generate /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz and just use the existing one, in contrast to Debian. I assume that the generation has to do once right and then it should work again and then call ´update-initramfs -u`.

It seems the file `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz` was **missing** on my system, and apparently, the responsible programs do not create it.

The **steps** that did work on my system:

1. `cd /etc/console-setup`
2. Find a file to use as template: `ls | grep kmap` (search for filenames containing 'kmap' in current folder). I choose `cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz`.
3. Create a duplicate of the template file and call it `cached.kmap.gz`: `sudo cp cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz cached.kmap.gz`(except NVIDIA drivers enabled via software & updates and grub quiet splash disabled because of [shutdown bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/982713))
4. run `sudo update-initramfs -u` so `cached.kmap.gz` can be integrated in the boot sequence.

(I tested that `cached.kmap.gz` whas being used by running `stat cached.kmap.gz` before and after step 4 and comparing the access timestamps.)

After reboot, cryptsetup would accept my LUKS pasphrase in my preferred keyboard layout, instead of QUERTY.

(That means `cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz` already contained the correct layout. If above method does not work for you, you may try your luck with one of the commands at [Change keyboard layout (English UK) on command line to English US](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us#new-answer?newreg=32a25cbe2ad34e5dbd1f0d2978691cb3) or https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/language-selector-gnome/)

I'm on kernel `4.13.0-32-generic' (check using`uname -r`). **Upgrading the kernel might mitigate the issue** as well, but I did not want to do that as I feared that would result in conflicts with the NVIDIA driver again. (Why I had to leave Fedora; after almost every kernel update, my system would turn unstable again, and I don't have the skills and time to solve that.)

* except NVIDIA drivers enabled via software & updates and grub quiet splash disabled because of [shutdown bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/982713)

Comment: Instead of grepping your keymap, the far easier way is to just run:  loadkeys <KeyboardName> and then dumpkeys | gzip -9 > cached.kmap.gz