# 17.10: "wlp1s0: failed to remove key", cannot shut down

Tags: shutdown, 17.10, cpu, thinkpad

I'm on a pretty fresh installation of 17.10 on a ThinkPad E460, and I'm not aware of screwing anything up.

First, I wasn't able to properly power off/reboot because of the error discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967441/17-1-wlp6s0-failed-to-remove-key-1-ffffffffffff-from-hardware-22). As advised in that thread, I upgraded the kernel, to 4.14.7.

Now, the `wlp1s0` error is gone, however, I get this when I attempt to shut it down:

```
sched: Unexpected reschedule of offline CPU#0!
```

[image]

The other solutions from the thread (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, GRUB edit) do nothing at all. So the only solution for me every time is to hold the power button which is not very safe.

Comment: How did you upgrade to that kernel? Looks like its incompatible with your hardware at least in its current configuration.

Comment: I used UKUU and chose this version as the newest stable. Using the kernel in Ubuntu repositories results in the wlp0s1 error, which is pretty much the same outcome as this. Will try, though.

Comment: What's "UKUU"? I never heard that acronym before.

Comment: Ubuntu kernel update utility. Very nice CLI/GUI kernel updater.

Comment: @DavidFoerster 'ukuu' was promited in [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu) not very long ago

Comment: I will vote this off-topic - this is a known bug - [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720930](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720930)

Answer (score 0):

Install kernel 4.13.1 and type:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove    
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Try to install wireless drivers online.