# Black screen after suspend

Tags: 17.10, suspend

Today I started getting a black screen when resuming my computer from sleep. Completely unresponsive. Couldn't even switch to another tty. Are a hard shutdown everything worked fine, but the same behavior reappeared after every suspend.

Naive as I was, I thought that maybe an update would solve the problem. Now after completing the upgrade I experience the same behaviour on boot. Right after the GRUB menu, the screen goes black. Choosing recovery mode and dropping to a root shell works as it's supposed to.

I've checked `boot.log`, `syslog` and the `systemd` logs and I can't find anything that looks like a serious problem. Here's a link to my [systemd output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbahe8dtbcjsnpd/journal?dl=0), in case it helps.

My computer runs the mini.iso release of Ubuntu 17.10.

I'm really stumped here an have no idea where to look right now. I'd really appreciate some help!

Thanks

EDIT: 
So it turns out that the suspension and boot to black screen were two separate problems. I managed to fix the boot problem by changing the grub config; it must have been messed up by the upgrade. The problem still remains after resuming from suspend however (closing the lid or running `systemctl suspend`)

EDIT 2: 
I found this error in my systemd logs: `wlp4s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)` which led me to [17.1 Wlp6s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967441/17-1-wlp6s0-failed-to-remove-key-1-ffffffffffff-from-hardware-22). I have now upgraded to kernel 4.15.0 but I'm still seeing the same issue.

It actually looks like the screen doesn't turn on at all. It's not just blank but completely black.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. Unfortunately I'm still seeing the same problem when resuming from suspension :/

Comment: Suspension is a radically different problem.  Did suspension ever work?

Comment: Yeah, it's been working fine since I bought the computer about 3 months ago and started misbehaving out of the blue yesterday

Comment: How was this marked as a duplicate? As Fabby mentioned, resuming from suspension is very different from booting

Comment: Yeah, you asked 2 questions in... well... one question! And one of those questions was solved by a duplicate...